# Program received signal: “0”. warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame

Tags: iphone

Mi app closes with this error,  when running an AdHoc build of my app in the device. I never have any problems in the simulator.

What's the exact meaning of this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a memory corruption issue.  You might try running with the NSZombieEnabled environment variable to make sure you're not accessing deallocated memory.  See http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

Comment: I'm loading all my textures inside the - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder method of my EAGLView, and the problem began as soon as I keep developping my app and adding new textures. The problem never happens with few textures, or if I load just certain parts of the game. What do You think ?. And thanks for Your help.

Answer (score 0):

ad hoc builds cannot be run under the debugger.  There is a "no debugger" flag in the executable.  Presumably this is done to frustrate reverse engineering of deployed apps.  Compile a release style build using a Development provision, it should have the same compiler and linker settings, but won't be no-debug.